# Ionic white space on right side of app

Tags: ios, css, ionic-framework, cross-platform, ionic-view

For almost all my views if I swipe left from the right edge of the phone or emulator the whole view moves to the left.

[image]

Comment: you should post the relevant code you have so we can help you better. but i suggest you try `html,body { overflow-x: hidden;}` even though this is an ugly solution and you should find the cause of that scroll in your code . something is surely causing that scroll

Comment: Code would be nice. This could be a number of things: padding, margins, overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the Ionic navbar was causing this issue. So I just made changes to the css file and that solved the issue.

```
.bar{overflow-x: hidden !important;}
```